# Como substituir a chave de uma array por uma variável?

Tags: javascript

Isto funciona:

```
var ind = 0;
var elementos = document.getElementsByName('significado');
var sig_txt = elementos[0].value;
alert(sig_txt);
```

retorna "madeira"

Por quê isto não funciona?

```
var ind = 0;
var elementos = document.getElementsByName('significado');
var sig_txt = elementos[ind].value;
alert(sig_txt);
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="significado"  value="madeira">
<input type="text" name="significado"  value="pedra">
<input type="text" name="significado"  value="cimento">
```

Comment: Aqui funcionou ambos os códigos com o mesmo resultado. Tem certeza que testou certo?

Comment: funciona sim! !!! estranha afirmação

Comment: Qual o erro retornado que só com você que não funciona? E aqui também funciona

Comment: Desculpem minha pergunta. Foi a primeira vez. Pensei que estivesse errado. Está funcionando.
Não incomodarei mais.
Grato

Comment: Veja @Lunes se pode perguntar a hora que você entender que precisa de ajuda, sinta se a vontade de pergunta sim ...